# Sound problems in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a digital audio (S/PDIF) driver installed. I can see that songs are played, but there are no sounds from my speakers and headphones. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: It is really hard to help you this way. Please be more specific: How do you connect your speakers/headphones to your computer? Which software are you using to play music? How did you configure your sound driver? Right click on the volume fader / speaker icon in the system tray and select "Mixer". Make a screenshot. Which playback device have you selected, etc.?

Comment: Please navigate to Control Panel > (select Small Icons from the view menu at the upper right) > Sound and go to the Playback tab (should be the first one). What devices are listed there? Which device has a green checkmark next to its icon?

Comment: @jcrawfordor I'm not on 7 atm but doesn't that default device icon have a mini equalizer next to it that animates when sound is played? If it does, it might be a good troubleshooting step while he's there.

Comment: Excellent point. it's a bar to the right of the device title. You should try playing some audio and seeing if that bar shows output.

Answer (score 2):

In your sound options, make sure that S/PDIF is selected as your default output. It could still be trying to send it to your 3.5mm jack.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to run the Windows 7 Sound Diagnostic to see if that can help reconcile the issue: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/no-sound-in-windows

Comment: You can also get to the diagnostic within your computer right now: C:\Windows\diagnostics\system\Audio\DiagPackage.diagpkg